# R - Array data loop selection

Tags: r, loops, multidimensional-array, matrix, nested-loops

i want to select June, July and August data from the 3D array (`ssta_sst`, 360*180*362).

the loop works but the output of ssta_winter has the identical values for `ssta_winter[,,i]`.seen below. I have set it up as an array of (360,180,29).

I think the problem is the variable `temp`, i want to define it as an array first but i don't know what size it should be (360,180,3) or (360,180,3*29) and how to keep a loop counter in `temp` when it passes down to finding mean stage?

```
ssta_winter = array( data=NA, dim = c(360,180,29))
temp = array( data=NA, dim = c(360,180,3))

for (yr in 1982:2010) {
    temp <- ssta_sst[,,year_sst==yr & (month_sst>=6 & month_sst<=8)]
    for (i in 1:360) {
        for (j in 1:180) {
            ssta_winter[i,j,] <- mean(temp[i,j,])
        }
    }
}

> for (i in 1:29){
+ print(ssta_winter[180,166,i])
+ }
[1] 0.2222583
[1] 0.2222583
[1] 0.2222583
[1] 0.2222583
[1] 0.2222583
[1] 0.2222583
[1] 0.2222583
[1] 0.2222583
[1] 0.2222583
[1] 0.2222583
[1] 0.2222583
[1] 0.2222583
[1] 0.2222583
[1] 0.2222583
[1] 0.2222583
[1] 0.2222583
[1] 0.2222583
[1] 0.2222583
[1] 0.2222583
[1] 0.2222583
[1] 0.2222583
[1] 0.2222583
[1] 0.2222583
[1] 0.2222583
[1] 0.2222583
[1] 0.2222583
[1] 0.2222583
[1] 0.2222583
[1] 0.2222583
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This : `mean(temp[i,j,])` will only produce a single value, so the LHS of that assignment should be `ssta_winter[i,j]`, and that means your dimensions for the means of winter (in the Southern Hemisphere) months should be only c(360,180). (And that explains the pattern you are puzzled by.)

If you want a single value for the "year" index, then you need to use that seq_along applied to the index inside your loop on the LHS of the assingment:

```
for (yr in seq_along(1982:2010 ) ) {
   temp <- ssta_sst[,,year_sst==(1982:2010)[yr] & (month_sst>=6 & month_sst<=8)]
   for (i in 1:360) {
     for (j in 1:180) {
        ssta_winter[i,j,yr] <- mean(temp[i,j,])
                                   }
                     }
                      }
```

Comment: But what i want is mean winter temperature for 29 years which ssta_winter[360,180,29]. How can i fix it?

Comment: See if my addendum is addressing your request.

Comment: that what i tried to do, but the year is too big, it says:"Error in ssta_winter[i, j, yr] <- mean(temp[i, j, ]) : 
  subscript out of bounds"

Comment: Sorry. I should have advise you to change the index to seq_along(). It was trying to put the value in the 1982nd slot and the matrix was not big enough.

Comment: Don't worry, i have figured it out. Just add another counter at begining k=0, then aft temp assignment, just write k=k+1, then replace ssta_winter[i, j, ] <- mean(temp[i,j, ]) by ssta_winter[i, j, k] <- mean(temp[i,j, ]). Aha, forget the most basic code.

Comment: The point is you cannot define the ssta_winter as [360,180,29] if you want to put year as the last row, also, if you do [360,180,1982:2010], R can't accept that big size.

Comment: Yes I understood all of that. You did not provide a reproducible example so I had nothing to test my code on. If you had provided a smaller dataset for testing it would have been immediately apparent.